# Image registration dataset

Tags: image-registration, data-request

I am searching for global purpose Dataset to test some image registration algorithm.. May you please give advice?
I am looking for color or gray-scale dataset. I prefer it not to be medical or binirized.
thanks

**EDIT:**

I found this dataset: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/data-aff.html
it seems good but it contains just few images (6 in each set)

Comment: Could you maybe use panorama stitching datasets such as the Adobe Panoramas Dataset

Comment: It is good suggestion. However, My Algorithm is about similar image not panorama.. If I could not find the data-set I need, I may go for Panorama sets.